# Android Studio : VPN service getting only the initial packet

Tags: android, kotlin, vpn

**Purpose:**
with BIND_VPN_SERVICE to intercept the traffic and try to log them in logcat.

**Problem:**
With my current code it is only intercepting the first URL after that it stops the interception.

**Code:**

```
package com.example.vpn_permission

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.VpnService
import android.util.Log
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

class MyVpnService : VpnService() {
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d("VPN", "VPN service started")
        val backgroundThread = Thread {
            configureAndStartVpn()
        }
        backgroundThread.start()
        return START_STICKY
    }

    private fun configureAndStartVpn() {
        try {
            val builder = Builder()
            builder.setSession(getString(R.string.app_name))
            builder.addRoute("192.168.30.0", 24)
            builder.addAddress("8.8.8.8", 32)
            prepare(this)
            val vpnInterface = builder.establish()

            if (vpnInterface != null) {
                val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024) // Adjust buffer size as needed

                while (true) {
                    try {
                        val fileInputStream = FileInputStream(vpnInterface.fileDescriptor)
                        val length = fileInputStream.read(buffer.array())

                        if (length > 0) {
                            val packet = buffer.array().sliceArray(0 until length)
                            logPacket(packet)
                        }
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        Log.e("Packet Logger", "Error reading packet: ${e.message}")
                    }
                    buffer.clear()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("VPN", "VPN configuration error: ${e.message}")
        }
    }

    private fun logPacket(packet: ByteArray) {
        val packetHex = packet.joinToString(" ") { String.format("%02X", it) }
        Log.d("Packet Logger", "Received packet: $packetHex")
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
2023-10-25 01:11:08.406 30332-30407 Packet Logger           com.example.vpn_permission           D  Received packet: 45 00 00 3C 70 AF 40 00 40 11 DB 48 08 08 08 08 C0 A8 1E 01 C2 20 00 35 00 28 AA 79 27 57 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 6D 08 66 61 63 65 62 6F 6F 6B 03 63 6F 6D 00 00 41 00 01
2023-10-25 01:11:08.408 30332-30407 Packet Logger           com.example.vpn_permission           D  Received packet: 45 00 00 41 70 B0 40 00 40 11 DB 42 08 08 08 08 C0 A8 1E 01 13 6A 00 35 00 2D FB 14 FF 52 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 73 74 61 74 69 63 02 78 78 05 66 62 63 64 6E 03 6E 65 74 00 00 01 00 01
2023-10-25 01:11:08.411 30332-30407 Packet Logger           com.example.vpn_permission           D  Received packet: 45 00 00 41 70 B1 40 00 40 11 DB 41 08 08 08 08 C0 A8 1E 01 37 72 00 35 00 2D 5E CA 37 95 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 73 74 61 74 69 63 02 78 78 05 66 62 63 64 6E 03 6E 65 74 00 00 41 00 01
2023-10-25 01:11:08.413 30332-30407 Packet Logger           com.example.vpn_permission           D  Received packet: 45 00 00 42 70 B2 40 00 40 11 DB 3F 08 08 08 08 C0 A8 1E 01 2D 06 00 35 00 2E A7 F8 BA E7 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 6B 61 69 6F 73 2D 64 08 66 61 63 65 62 6F 6F 6B 03 63 6F 6D 00 00 01 00 01
2023-10-25 01:11:08.415 30332-30407 Packet Logger           com.example.vpn_permission           D  Received packet: 45 00 00 42 70 B3 40 00 40 11 DB 3E 08 08 08 08 C0 A8 1E 01 69 8D 00 35 00 2E 24 6D 01 AC 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 6B 61 69 6F 73 2D 64 08 66 61 63 65 62 6F 6F 6B 03 63 6F 6D 00 00 41 00 01
2023-10-25 01:11:10.906 30332-30407 Packet Logger           com.example.vpn_permission           D  Received packet: 60 00 00 00 00 08 3A FF FE 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 98 6E 36 C4 F5 22 F9 FF 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 85 00 32 79 00 00 00 00
2023-10-25 01:11:18.800 30332-30407 Packet Logger           com.example.vpn_permission           D  Received packet: 60 00 00 00 00 08 3A FF FE 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 98 6E 36 C4 F5 22 F9 FF 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 85 00 32 79 00 00 00 00
2023-10-25 01:11:34.376 30332-30407 Packet Logger           com.example.vpn_permission           D  Received packet: 60 00 00 00 00 08 3A FF FE 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 98 6E 36 C4 F5 22 F9 FF 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 85 00 32 79 00 00 00 00
2023-10-25 01:12:05.096 30332-30407 Packet Logger           com.example.vpn_permission           D  Received packet: 60 00 00 00 00 08 3A FF FE 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 98 6E 36 C4 F5 22 F9 FF 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 85 00 32 79 00 00 00 00
2023-10-25 01:13:04.829 30332-30407 Packet Logger           com.example.vpn_permission           D  Received packet: 60 00 00 00 00 08 3A FF FE 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 98 6E 36 C4 F5 22 F9 FF 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 85 00 32 79 00 00 00 00
2023-10-25 01:15:07.710 30332-30407 Packet Logger           com.example.vpn_permission           D  Received packet: 60 00 00 00 00 08 3A FF FE 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 98 6E 36 C4 F5 22 F9 FF 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 85 00 32 79 00 00 00 00
```

**Explaination**
Packets starting with 45 are my facebook.com packages
after that even though I am browsing amazon.in it is not capturing that package. some random package is getting printed *packages starting with 60*

if I rerun my app and then browse amazon.in it will give me the amazon packet but after that will stop to record package.